# saving metadata on private storage instead of metaplex solana

Tags: solana, spl, metaplex

In Ethereum ERC-721 or ERC1155, off-chain metadata can be saved on private storage like S3. In solana, I want to use SPL to mint NFT with metadata on own storage, it is returning type mismatch error. Is it possible to use own/private storage for off-chain metadata with SPL instead of metaplex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Metaplex's Token Metadata Standard](https://docs.metaplex.com/token-metadata/Versions/v1.0.0/nft-standard) uses an "uri" field that points to a jsonFile. This json can be stored on any storage, like IPFS, AWS, Arweave, your own server, etc.

If you wanna mint some singles NFTs (instead of a collection) a fast and simple way is using [Metaboss's mint command](https://metaboss.rs/mint.html), that will create an on-chain NFT with the off-chain metadata (json) pointing to a storage. Metaboss is a Rust-CLI that has a lot of utilities for Solana-NFTs.

If you wanna create a NFT-collection I recommend you to use [Metaplex's Candy Machine](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/introduction) where you can use Arweave, IPFS, Pinata, NFT-Storage or AWS as storage, and you will be able to create the mint page so everyone can mint your project.

I hope this can solve your question, I will be looking if more questions appears through this one!.

Comment: when I use arwave file like https://ngclf5355kagziugifq2kau6u6e4b3jnjkmrhcddaai4mvujjvqq.arweave.net/aYSy933qgGyihkFhpQKep4nA7S1KmROIYwARxlaJTWE explorer reads all data correctly but if I upload same content on s3 json file and add its url in URI, it doesn't read image and attributes, rest is fine. any idea? @wrathiontbp

Comment: Can you share any link so I can test?

Comment: @murtzagondal Agreed. found an answer?